# HTLM5 App Storage facilities

Tags: ios, html, mobile

I need to create an iPad application. I was considering building an HTML 5 application based on Phone Gap. This application will be a file-synchronization application and will download pdf files and images from a central database.

Would an HTML 5 application makes sense here ? ... or do I need to go native because of storage requirements? I would need at least 1 GB of storage. From my research it seems that when you create an HTML 5 application, you have limited facilities for saving files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some tests on this: My conclusion is that in such case, you need to go for the native option.

This is because of a number of reasons:

The HTML 5 storage/file api has limited functionality and it is not yet fully standardized.

Furthermore, devices have different approaches for handling files especially with regards to shared storage.

Also, in some cases it is not possible to load some file types into the browser. For example, on IE (on WP) it is not possible to launch a pdf from the local file system. Sharing the data with a pdf program is not trivial because the html files are coupled with the specific application.